# How to speed up parsing an 10MB HTML file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, performance, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm parsing large HTMl files with Beautifulsoup that range between 3 and 10MB. Unfortunately, 99% of the data is content that I want to parse. The file practically contains a small header, a few js scripts and then between 1,000 and 10,000 items. Each items consists of the following table rows:

```
<tr class="New" id="content_id">
    <td class="item" align="center"> 
    </td><td align="center">
         <a onclick="somecode"><img src="/images/sample.gif" alt="alttext" class="image"></a>
    </td><td style="astyle">[content1]</td><td>[content2]</td><td>[content3]</td><td>[content4]</td><td>[content5]</td><td style="bstyle">[content6]</td><td>[content7]</td><td>[content8]</td><td>[content9]</td><td>[content10]</td><td>[content11]</td><td></td><td>[content12]</td><td>[content13]</td><td>
         <a href="somejs">[content14]</a>
    </td><td>
         <a href="somejs">[content15]</a>
    </td><td>[content16]</td><td>
         <a title="" href="somejs">[content16]</a>
    </td><td>
         <a title="" href="somejs">[content17]</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note every [content] placeholder is relevant data that I need to parse.

I have tried a variety of common optimizations such as a) using different parsers, b) using SoupStrainer, c) define encoding

b) and c) practically have no effect when I log the time it takes. The different parsers have a significant impact. When I run the script below on a 1.5k list of items (comparably small list), I'm getting the following parsing times (I am running the experiment on a 2012 Mac Book Air):

```
#1653 items parsed in 15.5 seconds with lxml
#xml takes 27 sec
#html5lib takes 69 sec
#html.parser takes 24 sec

current = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
strainer = SoupStrainer('table', attrs={'id':'contenttable'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml',parse_only=strainer,from_encoding="UTF-8")
print datetime.datetime.utcnow() - current
```

**Question: Besides what I have used so far, are there any tweaks I can use to dramatically shorten the parsing time?**

So far I can only think of increasing CPU power.

Comment: Are you loading the entire page at once? How are you parsing each line?  Perhaps you can parse one line at a time using generators (avoid memory problems with larger documents).

Comment: I'm sure I'll get bashed for this, because "HTML is not a regular language", but if each "item" is proper HTML like the one you've shown, you could iterate over the lines of the file (throw in a couple `next()` method calls for speeding up needless checks) and use regular expressions to extract the contents you need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're reading in the entire file into memory first, then there isn't much else you can do. If the HTML is broken in quite a few places, then the parsers have to perform more work to try and guess the correct structure.

When it comes to parsing XML/HTML in Python, it has been my experience that `lxml` has been the fastest and most memory efficient (compared to something like `xml.minidom` or BeautifulSoup).

However, I have parsed simple XML files larger than 10MB in less than 15 seconds, so it leads me to believe that you may have really nasty/heavily nested HTML which is choking the parser. Either that or my hardware is just crazy awesome (i7 2700k and an SSD).

Answer (score 2):

lxml looks to be the best solution in Python.

[image]

We benchmark the all parser / platform when building: serpapi.com
https://medium.com/@vikoky/fastest-html-parser-available-now-f677a68b81dd

Comment: I came to the same conclusion a while back. I never understood why BS is popular.

Comment: @pguardiario cuz it's syntax is really easy to use for parsing regardless the kind of websites. Do you have other suggestions,

Comment: My suggestion is to use lxml + css. Easier syntax and better performance.

Comment: CSS is definitely a good way to parse HTML. And it can tested easily from the browser console using `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using lxml `iterparse` and remove nodes on every iteration. Here is an [excellent article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) which talks about how to parse huge files. See the solution in the end.

Comment: `iterparse` is good when you care about keeping memory usage down, but will not parse any faster than the regular `parse()` method. They both construct the same tree.